# Optimizing MYSQL statements

Tags: mysql, optimization

Recently, I started working on a project, where I came across many MySQL statements like this:

```
SELECT s.Important, c.Interesting
FROM table1 s, table2 c 
WHERE s.IdForTableC = c.id
```

or

```
SELECT q.Important, c.Interesting 
FROM table1 q, table2 p, table3 c 
WHERE q.IdInTableP = p.id 
AND p.IdInTableC = c.id 
AND c.Measure = 1
```

I am completely new to optimizing MySQL and read a few guides that advised me to use `EXPLAIN SELECT`. I did and get type `all` for the above query and type `index` for the second one. I guess this means, that both queries should be optimized, but I don't know how. Is it even possible without changing the whole structure of the database?

EDIT: the EXPLAIN output of the first one is:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '467', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 's', 'ref', 'IdInTableC', 'IdInTableC', '5', 'table2.c.id', '2', 'Using where'
```

and INDEXES are:

```
'table2', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '14184441', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'table2', '1', 'otherID', '1', 'otherID', 'A', '92708', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'table2', '1', 'IdInTableC', '1', 'IdInTableC', 'A', '3048', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Could you [add](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/234664/edit) the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to your question without disclosing any confidential information? Otherwise your question becomes sort of "open-ended" and might be closed as  [**too broad**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Each query id optimized separately. In complex you must search some optimal balance only. Anycase DDLs, index statistic (including selectivity by predicates from the query) and EXPLAIN for a query is compulsory.

Comment: Have you tried using the ANSI `JOIN` syntax in these queries? And explained their plans? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @hot2use I added the explain statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1**

`EXPLAIN` is not simple to follow.  First, let me explain how to optimize the two queries.

```
SELECT s.Important, c.Interesting
FROM table1 s, table2 c 
WHERE s.IdForTableC = c.id
```

That's the old way to write a `JOIN`; please learn the new way:

```
SELECT s.Important, c.Interesting
    FROM table1 s
    JOIN table2 c  ON s.IdForTableC = c.id
```

The `ON` explains how the two table relate to each other.

Now there is no filtering via a `WHERE` clause, so all that can be done is

1. Go through all the rows of one of the tables.  (No index is useful)
2. Foreach row, reach into the other table.

If `s` is used for step 1, then an index on `id` is needed in `c` for step 2.
If `c` is used for step 1, then an index on `IdForTableC` is needed in `s` for step 2.

The convention is to name the `PRIMARY KEY` "`id`".  A table must have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  I'll guess that `c` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  This makes starting with `s` a slam-dunk.  But, instead, the Optimizer decided to start with `c` -- as seen by it being row 1 in the `EXPLAIN`.

"ALL" means that the entire table is scanned.  Some of the NULLs go along with that.  "PRIMARY" does not mean much in this context.  `c` has *about* 467 rows.

To get into `s`, it used `table2.c.id`.  Something is wrong there.  That syntax says "database table2, table c, column id".  Is your database called "table2".  Ugh.

The index named `IdInTableC` was used.  Presumably, you had

```
INDEX(IdInTableC)
```

so that name is the same as the column.  `5` probably means it is a `NULLable` `INT`.  Use `NOT NULL` unless you have a purpose for `NULL`.  The `JOIN` will find an *estimated* 2 rows in `s`.

I guessed wrong as to which order `c` and `s` would be used.  But the symmetry of the query implies that there *might not* be a lot of difference in which to start with.

**Query 2**

Again, let's use the new `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT q.Important, c.Interesting 
    FROM table1 q
    JOIN table2 p  ON q.IdInTableP = p.id
    JOIN table3 c  ON p.IdInTableC = c.id
    WHERE  c.Measure = 1
```

It is usually best to "filter" first.  The only filter is `c.Measure = 1`, so `c` will probably be the first table, especially if you have

```
INDEX(Measure)
```

Then, the chain must be:  c -> p -> q.  So these are needed:

```
p:  INDEX(IdInTableC)
q:  INDEX(IdInTableP)
```

With those indexes, all three tables should use `INDEX`, perhaps with `ref` or `eq_ref`.

**More Tips**

In the Extras column:

- "Using index" means that the index is "covering".  That is, all the columns needed are found in the index.  This is a minor performance boost.
- "Using index condition" is different and mostly out of your control; it also implies a perf boost.
- "Using join buffer" -- the second table is fully loaded into memory; this may be a big perf boost.
- "Using temporary, Using filesort" -- People wrongly fear these.  There is some performance loss, but usually one or both are required.  After all, `ORDER BY` implies a sort.  The *absence* of "filesort" implies an optimization that is sometimes available.

For some basic index-creation tips, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

I don't use `EXPLAIN` that much; I try to go straight from the `SELECT` to the optimal index.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful and well explained!